# to retrieve the latest control values(checkbox,datetimepicker) in a different class in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to access the latest checkstates and the latest set date value using a function called GetProfileFilter. Now my problem is I'm not able to fetch the latest values when either the checkbox.Checkstate is changed or the datetimepicker is changed.I'm setting the values based on whether the checkboxes are set and I intend to use the IBitWise value elsewhere.Note that at form load all the checkboxes are checked.In the form class I have nothing more than a few variable and the event handlers for buttons and checkboxes and date time pickers.Open to all suggestions!!

```
class Profile{
     public bool GetProfileFilter()
    {
        if (frmInactive.btnApplyWasClicked == true || frmInactive.btnCancelWasClicked == false)
        {
            frmInactive.ShowDialog();
            MessageBox.Show("Here");
            if (frmInactive.chkCancel.Checked == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cancel");
                IBitWise += Canceled;
            }
            if (frmInactive.chkDiscon.Checked == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Discon");
                IBitWise += Discontinued;
            }
            if (frmInactive.chkVoidwoRes.Checked == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Voidedwo");
                IBitWise += VoidedWoutRes;
            }
            if (frmInactive.chkVoidwRes.Checked == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Voidedw");
                IBitWise += VoidedWRes;
            }  
            MessageBox.Show("Ibit value:" + IBitWise);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }    
    }
```

}

```
    public partial class FilterView : Form
{
    Utilities Utilities = new Utilities();
    //FilterView filterView = new FilterView();
    public FilterView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void checkBox5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void rsetbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void aplybtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        callonload();
    }

    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dateTimePicker2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: The property in the design.cs file is private.  You also have to access the value through an instance of the class.  So first pass the from instance to the class : public bool GetProfileFilter(FilterView filterView). Then you can either create a public method for getting the control value or change the property to public in the designer.cs file.

Comment: @jdweng i've set the property in designer to public still isn't working

Comment: You need the same instance of the form to get the value.

Comment: @jdweng correct so i pass them in the function getprofilefilter?....how exactly does that work?

Comment: It doesn't get the latest value.  Only the value when you call the method.  You want latest value which means you need to be a reference to the form or control.

Comment: @jdweng can you please specify how its done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample code with checkbox made public

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Profile profile = new Profile(this);
            profile.GetProfileFilter();
        }
    }
    class Profile
    {
        Form1 form1;

        public Profile(Form1 form1)
        {
            this.form1 = form1;
        }

        public bool GetProfileFilter()
        {
            form1.checkBox1.Checked = true;
            return true;
        }


    }
}
```